# I send parameter value from url to html in appsscript, but does not recognize it

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I send parameter value from url to html in appsscript, but does not recognize it.
I have trouble passing the value of a variable from a parameter in the url to a html appscript.

Could you please help me, I've tried everything and does not work.
Show an example below

Url

```
https://script.google.com/a/<#######>/s/<script>/exec?clave=hola
```

Código.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  template.clave=e.parameter.clave

  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('page')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
<label for="id-cfolio" id="id-lfolio">field  : </label><input type="text" size="6"  id="id-cfolio" readonly  />
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("id-cfolio").value = clave; 

}
```

Comment: This question was [crossposted](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13811/pasar-valor-de-par%C3%A1metro-desde-url-hasta-html) to Stack Overflow en Español with a different user account. Ask that your accounts be merged. To learn how, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738587/pass-url-parameter-into-web-app-script/

Comment: Hi, thanks Ruben, yes I see the related question, but, I can't make it works.
I have 2 days making changes and I don't known that is wrong.

Comment: Please take a look to the answer that I posted to the crosspoted question: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13857/65

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("id-cfolio").value = <?=clave?>; 

}
```